# using the term image in different contexts

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage

**art**  :       a duplication of the visual form of a person or object

**psychology** :  the public personality or character presented by a person

**business/ marketing**:   an advertising concept conveyed to the public

**literature**:  a symbol or metaphor that represents something else

Would you please write or give me an example sentence for each context?

Although I have tried much, in fact, failed to write them. Or, could you please give me some advices as to where or how I could mange to write such an example or sentences?

My example( extracted from Oxford Dictionary): ***art***:  Her work juxtaposed ***images*** from serious and popular art

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Cheers,
 nima

Comment: Check out [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/image), 2b for your *art*, 3 for your *literature*, 1 for your *psychological, business, marketing*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have asked for is quite complicated but for art you could say 
" He created an **image** of the person " or " He copied the **image** "

For psychology you could say 
" His **image** in the public eye was not a good one " or " He created an **image** of violence.

In this case it might be better to say " He gave off an **air** of violence " or even " He gave off an **auora** of violence " if you were describing the person as if they were standing in front of you. The other sentences would be if you got the description from somebody else ( second hand information ).

Business/marketing - this is very similar to the psychology. You could use the same sentences and swap "he" for "it". But if you are talking about an advertisement it would be more positive.
For example "The **image** it conveyed was one of excitement" or " The **image** it gave off was one of excitement "

Again in this case you might be better saying " It **looked** exciting " or " The **feeling** it gave off was one of excitement "

Litrature - here you can use the word **imagery**.
" The **imagery** in the poem compared the rising of the sun to the beuty of a flower "

You could also say " The **image** of the tree in the poem was very well described " but it might be better to say " The tree was so well described that he could see it clearly in his mind "

Finally you could also say " The description created a clear **image** in his mind "
In this case you could swap the word image for picture.